# How to set a cookie for a Gatling scenario

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have the following code. The problem is that the cookie is not being set for the requests that follow.

I would like to set a single cookie that is used by all of the subsequent requests (including the `ajaxRequests`).

```
val get = scenario("Page")
  .feed(myfeed)
  .group("Home Page") {
    exec(session => setSessionVariables(session))
      .exec(addCookie(Cookie("mycookie", "true").withDomain(baseurl)))
      .exec(http("Home Page")
        .get(pageUrl)
        .resources(
          ajaxRequest01,
          ajaxRequest02
        ))
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is that the problem here is that the **baseUrl** you are using includes the protocol - e.g. https://www.google.com/ etc.

From my experimentation with this feature, this won't work, the cookie needs to be passed just the domain - e.g. **www.google.com** or just **.google.com** if you want it to apply across subdomains.